# Swift: initialising a nested class

Tags: swift, class, nested, initialization

I was wondering if one can initialise a nested class, e.g. setting the tyre pressure when initialising the car:

```
class Tyre {
    var pressure : Double = 0.0

    init() { }

    init(withPressure p: Double) {
        self.pressure = p
    }
}

class Car {
    var tyre = Tyre()
}

// should return 2.5
let myCar = Car().tyre(withPressure : 2.5).pressure
```

Now only this works, with the default init():

```
let myCar = Car().tyre.pressure  // return 0.0
```

Thanks your your reply in advance!

Comment: Sure but you have to write a Car initializer that initializes the Tyre.

Comment: I understand that. I was just wondering why the default init can be (and is!)  used and why you can't use a init with parameters. Perhaps this is a noob question, but I thought that with "Car().tyre(withPressure : 2.5)" tyre also is being initialised. But I guess not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't quite do that, but you can pass in a custom Tyre as a parameter to your car's init:

```
class Tyre {
    var pressure : Double = 0.0

    init() { }

    init(withPressure p: Double) {
        self.pressure = p
    }
}

class Car {
    var tyre: Tyre!

    init(withTyre t: Tyre) {
        self.tyre = t
    }
}

let myCar = Car(withTyre: Tyre(withPressure : 2.5))

// should return 2.5
let pressure = myCar.tyre.pressure
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `tyre` separately. You could do it two ways. Either `Car` could take a type pressure parameter:

```
class Car {
    var tyre

    init(withTyrePressure tyrePressure: Double) {
        tyre = Tyre(withPressure: tyrePressure)
    }
}
```

Or `Car` can take a `tyre` parameter:

```
class Car {
    var tyre

    init(withTyre tyre: Tyre) {
        self.tyre = tyre
    }
}

let tyre = Tyre(withPressure: 2.5)
let car = Car(withTyre: tyre)
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative!

Comment: This is the best answer because it shows both choices for how to write your Car initializer. But either way, what you (the OP) are asking to do requires a Car initializer. You cannot magically violate the rules of language syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Tyre {
    var pressure : Double = 0.0

    init() { }

    init(withPressure p: Double) {
        self.pressure = p
    }
}

class Car {
    var tyre : Tyre
    init(withPressure p:Double) { // <-- this is the only change from your code
        self.tyre = Tyre(withPressure:p)
    }
}

// should return 2.5
let myCar = Car(withPressure : 2.5)
myCar.tyre.pressure // 2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Tyre {
    var pressure : Double = 0.0

    init() { }

    init(withPressure p: Double) {
        self.pressure = p
    }
}

class Car {
    var tyre = Tyre()
}

// should return 2.5
let myCar = Car()

myCar.tyre = Tyre(withPressure: 2.5)

print(myCar.tyre.pressure)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question but had to change the class Car by using a function tyre that returns the class Tyre instead of using a property. So it **can** be done! ;-)

The below example might not make sense, but is just a proof of principle...

```
class Tyre {
    var pressure : Double = 0.0

    init() { }

    init(withPressure p: Double) {
        self.pressure = p
    }
}

class Car {
    //var tyre = Tyre(withPressure: 2.5)

    func tyre (withPressure p: Double) -> Tyre {
        return Tyre(withPressure: p)
    }
}


let myCar = Car().tyre(withPressure: 2.2).pressure
```